# Exhausted Iterator, But no Error in For Loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator

(In Python 3.2)

```
miters = map(abs,(-1,2,5))
for i in miters:
    print(i)
1
2
5

next(miters)
--> StopIteration

for i in miters:
    print(i)
--> ?? Nothing Happens..
```

Why can't I get 'StopIteration' Error Message in the second for loop?
'miter' has been exhausted, so if I loop it again, I think there would be a 'StopIteration'...

Can any one tell me why?

Comment: @MartijnPieters nice answer :) Bookmarking that one

Answer (score 4):

The `for` loop uses `StopIteration` to work out when to stop. So it swallows the exception and stops immediately.